# Has there ever been a Marvel television show with a (consistent) opening intro with sung/spoken lyrics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, tv

Marvel has a slew of television shows that it has released over the years, from MCU television shows more recently (*Wandavision*, *Loki*, *Hawkeye*, and more) to ABC/Hulu/Netflix shows (*Daredevil*, *Runaways*, *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*) to legacy animation television (*Spider-Man*, *X-Men* (1997), and so on) as well as other categories I probably haven't heard of. However, all the shows I've seen with a consistent opening/closing theme (*or one changing season-to-season, but not episode-to-episode*) - think *Hawkeye*, *Wandavision* (closing theme; it's opening one changes episode-to-episode), *X-Men*, or *Runaways* - don't have words to them. **My question is, is there a Marvel television show or shows that have a theme song that has spoken or sung lyrics, consistently through at least a season or more?** Any Marvel show, from any year, qualifies.

Comment: “Spider-man, spider-man, does whatever a spider can”.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

##### *Spider-Man: The Animated Series* (1994)

Lyrics:

> Spider-Man, Spider-Man
> Radioactive Spider-Man
>
> Spider blood, spider blood,
> Radioactive spider blood

-

> Marvel outsourced the show's music to distributors Saban Entertainment, who were also responsible for the music in the concurrent [*X-Men* cartoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series) airing on Fox Kids. The theme for the series was performed by [Joe Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Perry_(musician)) of the [hard rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_rock) band [Aerosmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosmith), although the song was written by [Shuki Levy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuki_Levy). Levy, [Haim Saban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haim_Saban) and Udi Harpaz are credited as composers of the orchestral background score.

<sup>- ["Spider-Man: The Animated Series" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1994_TV_series)#Music)</sup>

---

##### *Spider-Man* (1978 Japanese TV series)

> ###### Opening theme
>
> - "**Kakero! Spider-Man**" (駆けろ！スパイダーマン, *Kakero! Supaidāman*, Run! Spider-Man)
> - Lyrics: [Saburo Yatsude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saburo_Yatsude)
> - Composition & Arrangement: Michiaki Watanabe (listed as Chumei Watanabe)
> - Artist: [Yuki Hide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuki_Hide)

<sup>- ["Spider-Man (Japanese TV series)" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(Japanese_TV_series)#Theme_songs)</sup>

---

##### *Iron Man: The Animated Series* (1994)

###### Season 2 opening theme

> The first season's theme song was replaced in the second season by an intense [electric guitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_guitar) theme (composed by William Kevin Anderson), featuring the repeated refrain of "I am Iron Man!", while showing Tony Stark beating red-hot iron plates into shape with a blacksmith's hammer (possibly to mimic the [Black Sabbath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sabbath) song "[Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_(song))").

<sup>- ["Iron Man: The Animated Series" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_(TV_series)#Second_season)</sup>

---

##### *Fantastic Four: The Animated Series* (1994)

###### Season 1 and 2 opening theme

---

##### *Silver Surfer: The Animated Series* (1998)

> The title theme music to the animated series had Latin-sounding singing interspersed at ominous points against the instrumental background.

<sup>- ["Silver Surfer: The Animated Series" TV Tropes article](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/SilverSurferTheAnimatedSeries)</sup>

---

##### *The Avengers: United They Stand* (1999)

Lyrics:

> Avengers…

-

> Opening theme: "The Avengers: United They Stand" by Sky Flyers

<sup>- ["The Avengers: United They Stand" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers:_United_They_Stand)</sup>

---

##### *The Spectacular Spider-Man* (2008)

> The title sequence for the show was directed by Victor Cook with the theme song written and performed by The Tender Box.

<sup>- ["The Spectacular Spider-Man" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_(TV_series)#Production)</sup>

---

##### *Iron Man: Armored Adventures* (2009)

> Popular rock band [Rooney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooney_(band)) recorded the theme song to the series.

<sup>- ["Iron Man: Armored Adventures" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man:_Armored_Adventures#Theme_song)</sup>

---

##### *The Super Hero Squad Show* (2009)

> Theme music composer: [Parry Gripp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parry_Gripp), [David Ari Leon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Ari_Leon)

<sup>- ["The Super Hero Squad Show" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Super_Hero_Squad_Show)</sup>

---

##### *The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes* (2010)

> Theme music composer: [Guy Erez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_Erez), [David Ari Leon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Ari_Leon)
> Opening theme: "Fight As One"
> by [Bad City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_City)

<sup>- ["The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers:_Earth%27s_Mightiest_Heroes)</sup>

---

##### *Spidey and His Amazing Friends* (2021)

> [Patrick Stump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Stump), known from the pop punk rock band [Fall Out Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_Out_Boy), performed the theme song for the series and is the songwriter and composer. Stump, a longtime Marvel fan, used themes from previous *Spider-Man* media as inspiration for the series' theme song.

<sup>- ["Spidey and His Amazing Friends" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spidey_and_His_Amazing_Friends_(2021_TV_series)#Music)</sup>

---

##### *Moon Girl and Devil Dinosaur* (2023)

> [...] the theme song, "Moon Girl Magic," written and produced by executive music producer Raphael Saadiq and performed by series star Diamond White (voice of Lunella aka Moon Girl), was revealed today during a Marvel's panel at New York Comic Con.

<sup>- [*NYCC 2022: 'Marvel's Moon Girl and Devil Dinosaur' Will Be Back with Season 2*. Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/articles/tv-shows/nycc-2022-moon-girl-and-devil-dinosaur-season-2)</sup>

---

##### *Echo* (2024)

The opening theme for Season 1 of *Echo* is [“Burning” by Yeah Yeah Yeahs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSffKUyr0lk).

Comment: Great answer! Seems like you got it pretty well covered.

Comment: Although, the other answer has ones you don't.

Comment: Came here just to make sure someone posted EMH. In my house, we don't skip that intro when watching that show.

Comment: @PeterNielsen I don't think this site's answer culture obligates completeness.  In the sense different answers can complement each other.

Comment: @MatthewGreen What does the Emergency Medical Hologram have to do with Marvel TV shows?

Comment: @MasonWheeler that guy just really loved his music.

Comment: I wish that I could upvote this answer more than once.  Great roundup of videos.  But I remembered one you missed, the 1995 Iron Man cartoon.  I guess the correct thing to do is post it as another answer, but if you want to add it to yours I'd be fine with it.  You reminded me of it and inspired me to look it up.

Comment: @steveha Thanks for mentioning the Iron Man cartoon. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Was looking for 'Fight as One'.  Great song, wish it had a full length version and wasn't lost to the ages...

Comment: Is the first video really vocals?  Sounds like "singing guitar" / synth to make some word sounds overlayed on the guitar riffs.  Worth at least mentioning, but seems a poor choice for the first entry in an answer.  Especially since I was expecting the Spidey intro I remember from childhood, apparently the 1967 version.  I undid my upvote after playing the video, at first thinking there were no vocals, only hearing them on the 2nd listen after seeing no comments saying wrong video. Then reapplied my upvote after hearing the comment-recommended vocal stylings of the Emergency Medical Hologram :P

Comment: @PeterCordes The 1967 Spider-Man cartoon intro was already mentioned in an answer prior to this one, so I didn't add it here. As for the 1994 Spider-Man cartoon intro, I'm pretty sure it's the vocals of Joe Perry (of Aerosmith fame). It does sound like synth sounds, which is why I included the lyrics to clarify that it's vocals.

Answer (score 21):

Iron Man 1966 is so epic MCU Tony Stark uses it as his cellphone ring tone.

Thor

There's various other 1966 cartoons- maybe I'll add later

End Credits (song not video) for all the 1966 cartoons according to IMDB

Spider-Man 1967 also iconic

Comment: The 1967 Spider-Man cartoon intro is iconic.

Comment: "also iconic"?!  ALSO?!

Comment: Huh. I was born around the year these came out, but the only one I'm familiar with is the Spiderman cartoon. Where the heck did the other 2 go?

Comment: @T.E.D. I had a friend now deceased (would be about 70 now) who regained all of his marvel #1 issues because when his parents died he found them in a safe.  But one of his last purchases was for a 1960s fan club record with the marching theme - the end theme credits for the 66 cartoons. It annoyed him since he was a boy since he sent in cash to join the club and never got anything back.  He was able to tell Stan Lee the story about his parents.

Answer (score 4):

This one gets my vote for the most metal of Marvel cartoon intros: The 1995 *Iron Man* cartoon.  "I am Iron Man!"

Comment: I'm guessing some suit demanded "I Am Iron Man" for the intro song, but didn't give them "buy a song from Black Sabbath's record label" $ to do it, so they commissioned this piece and played dumb.